# General rule about which Pandas operations on Series keep the name?

Tags: python, pandas

Sometimes when I do operations on Pandas Series, the resulting Series has the same 'name' attribute. Other times, the resulting Series has an empty 'name' attribute and I have to set it manually. Is there a general rule of thumb about which categories of operations on Series keep the name, and which do not?

Update:

The first person to comment below asked for an example, so I went ahead and came up with the first example out of my trial and error just now:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> s = pd.Series([2, 4, 6, 8], name = 'ThisIsMyName')
>>> np.sqrt(s)
0    1.414214
1    2.000000
2    2.449490
3    2.828427
Name: ThisIsMyName, dtype: float64
>>> pd.rolling_mean(s, 2)
0   NaN
1     3
2     5
3     7
dtype: float64
>>>
```

Notice how the result of `np.sqrt` keeps the name `ThisIsMyName` but the result of `pd.rolling_mean` no longer has the name `ThisIsMyName` (so I would have to set it manually afterward). I'm just trying to get a sense of the general rule of thumb (if there is one) so I'm not surprised/confused all the time about operations keeping or losing the name of the Series.

Comment: can you provide examples of both types of operations?

Comment: @PaulH Sure I can. Will do in a minute.

Comment: I suspect the `rolling_*` (and `expanding_*`) functions specifically have different behavior because they are different under the hood (i.e., they are not provided by numpy).  They probably should preserve the name but may not just due to no one getting around to it.